# Showing an unknown type in Haskell (basic)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

i'm currently learning Haskell and I have difficulties with a task.

I have a non-empty Binary Tree which looks like this

```
data STree a = BinS (STree a) a (STree a) | LeftS (STree a) a | RightS a (STree a) | LeafS a
```

All I try to do right now is understanding how to output this tree.

As for the beginning I just want to output the case for LeafS a

I tried this

```
instance Show (STree a) where
show (LeafS b) = show b
```

I just dont know how to convert this unknown type a to a String that I can output. I tried show, print, everything i can think of but nothing works.

The tree will only contain integers later on, but I have to do it with type a...

This is what I want: LeafS 2 ~> "2"
LeafS "100" ~> "100"

Comment: You tried something and probably the compiler gave you a very useful error message explaining why it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every type can be `show`n in Haskell. Some types cannot be shown inherently - e.g. type `Int -> Int` - how do you show that? But some types just don't yet have an implementation of `show`. So in general, if you have some type `a` about which you know nothing, you cannot assume that it can be `show`n.

In order to use the function `show` on your type `a`, you need to ask the compiler to make sure that type `a` has an instance of `Show a`. To do that, you add a *constraint* to your instance, like this:

```
instance Show a => Show (STree a) where
    show (LeafS b) = show b
    ...
```

Because you have specified `Show a =>`, the compiler knows that a given type `STree a` is an instance of the `Show` class if and only if the type `a` itself is. This allows the compiler to call `show b` and be sure that, when all types become known, this call will be possible. On the flip side, anyone who tries to `show` an instance of `STree a` will need to make sure that there exists an instance `Show a`, and the compiler will check that and issue an error if that is not so.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot